# ReactJS: Can't ready property xxx of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm aware that there are a lot of questions asking the same thing but none of those answers seem to work for my specific case and I have been at this for hours and still can't figure it out. I'm following a ReactJs tutorial for a WeatherApp.I get back an object from an API call that looks like this:

```
{
    current: {}
    forecast:
        forecastday:[ //
            0: {...}
            1: {...}
            2: {...}
            3: {...}
            4: {...}
        ] //Array of five objects
    location: {}
} //this object is part of a bigger response object
```

When I `console.log(objectName.forecast.forecastday)` I get back the array, which means it's actually there.

But when I try

```
var forecastData = props.forecast.data;
var days = forecastData.forecast.forecastday.map(function (day) {
       //do something
 });
```

it gives me back the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forecast' of undefined`. I have also tried logging `forecastData` and it comes back just fine. `forecast` is clearly there so unless I'm missing something extremely obvious, I don't know what's going on.

Thanks.

Comment: maybe `var forecastData = props.forecast.data;` this is giving the problem? If `forecastData` is giving you correct data

Comment: `props.forecast.data` is `undefined`. Make sure the prop is being passed correctly by the parent component. Try adding a `console.log(this.props)` to your render function and inspect what's being passed in.

Comment: Are you handling the initial render when there is no data correctly? The block that is causing issues should only be accessible once the api calls has completed. My feeling is you have no such protection and this code is being called before the api cal comes back up updates state/props.

Comment: Maybe it should be `this.props` instead of just `props`

Comment: Three reasons: 1. you need to use this.props , 2. inside your forecast , there is nothing called data, so forecastData will be undefined, and in your second line, your cannot read forecast from undefined. 3. even you use var forecastData = this.props.forecast in your first line, second line is not correct because forecast is being referred once again. try:
`var forecastData = this.props.forecast;` 
`var days = forecastData.forecastday.map(function(day){ \\ do something});`

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely not taking into account the initial state, where `props.forecast.data` may be undefined at the initial mount of the component since your API call is happening asynchronously.

You can do something like this:

```
var days = forecastData
  ? forecastData.forecast.forecastday.map(function (day) {
    //do something
  })
  :  null;
```

This will first check to see if `forecastData` exists, and if it does exist, it will map over the `forecastData.forecast.forecastday` array.

If forecastData does not exist, then that variable will render null.